# Equal spacing of Labels in VStack resembling a List using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do you make the images in labels equal spacing in a VStack like they would be in a List?

Here is an example. I would like each image in the label to take the same amount of width spacing as they would in a List.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Label("Hello, world!", systemImage: "globe")
            Label("Hello, world!", systemImage: "bubble.left.and.bubble.right.fill")
            Label("Hello, world!", systemImage: "bubble.right")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your own `LabelStyle`, and decide exactly what your label should look like.

```
struct MyStyle: LabelStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            configuration.icon
                // fix your width here
                // width could also be passed as a initialiser parameter
                .frame(width: 50)
            configuration.title
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Label("Hello, world!", systemImage: "globe")
    Label("Hello, world!", systemImage: "bubble.left.and.bubble.right.fill")
    Label("Hello, world!", systemImage: "bubble.right")
}
.labelStyle(MyStyle())
```